# Can't access MySQL database in Django VirtualEnv on localhost

Tags: python, mysql, django, mysql-error-1045

I have had a virtualenv for Trunk up and running for a while, but now I am trying to branch, and get things setup on another virtualenv for my 'refactor' branch.

Everything looks to be setup correctly, but when I try to run any manage.py commands, I get this error:

`_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'brian'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")`

I just don't understand why it's not attempting to use the password I have set in my django settings file.  Is there some addition mysql setup I could have overlooked?  Does this issue ring any bells for anyone?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are both virtualenvs running on the same physical machine?

Comment: I'm having the same problem in one machine. It ssems that django is not importing the settings from settings.py and failing silently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem I was having. 
Django was importing a different settings.py file.

I had another django project inside my django product like `myproject/myproject/`.

Instead of importing `myproject/settings.py`, it was importing `myproject/myproject/settings.py`

I assume that Aptana Studio created that project there. If you use eclipse you are also likely to have this problem.